# Change datagrid selected item using two comboboxes

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid, combobox

I have a datagrid containing information about users

```
  UserName    UserID    UserHobby
```

And I have a comboBox which is linked to each of the columns above.
If a user select any of the boxes individually it brings the selected datagrid row to the first occurance of a matching row. However If for instance a user selects a value "Bryan" is UserName and a hobby "golf" I want the selected cell to move to a row where both values are present.

At the moment my selectedIndexChanged code for the second combobox is as follows :

```
DataGrid.SelectedRows = 
          DataGrid.SelectedRows.Where(
          x =>x.Row.Field<string>(DataGrid.Text)
          .Contains(HobbyCombobox.Text));
```

However this is not working , would anyone have a similar approach or solution

Based on feedback from answers my code now looks like this

```
  var query = DataGrid.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Where(x => x.Row.Field<string> (DataGrid.Text).Contains(comboBox10.Text));
          DataGrid.DataSource = query.ToList();
          DataGrid.Refresh()
```

However this is throwing an error on x.Row

```
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for  'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type  'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'
```

Comment: Any error? What kind of .NET version are you using? I ask this because I'm using `.NET 3.5` and in fact we have to use `OfType<DataGridViewRow>()` or `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()` before we can use `LINQ`.

Comment: @KingKing Using 4.0 , the error was to do with the use of where "no definition"  what way would I rewrite the query to include "OfType<DataGridViewRow>()" ?

Comment: I don't understand your idea well. What do you want to filter? Normally we set `DataSource` of a `DataGrid` to a `List` of some object and **all the properties** of that object will **become your DataGrid Columns**, if you set the `DataGrid.DataSource` like as in your code, your grid will have all the columns corresponding to **all the properties of a `DataGridViewRow` object**. That's so messy and may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid.SelectedRows is read only.
you need to rebind the datasource.

```
var query = DataGrid.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Where(x =>x.Row.Field<string>(DataGrid.Text).Contains(HobbyCombobox.Text));
DataGrid.DataSource=query;
DataGrid.Refresh();
```

Comment: In `winforms`, `DataGrid.DataSource = query` would not work, we have to perform the query by `ToList()` to make it work.

Comment: @Tim.Tang using your code throws the following error       'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)